# MSVC is linking to release libraries in debug build instead of debug versions

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, static-libraries

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (C++). I am having a solution which I want to build in debug mode. I am referencing some third party libraries (e.g. MyGUI). By the end of the debug build the linker gives a fatal error (LNK1104) that "MyGUIEngine.lib" cannot be found. So actually in debug mode the linker should link to "MyGUIEngine_d.lib". Why does it look for the release version of this library?

I am building Multithreaded-Debug-DLL (/MDd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "C/C++" -> "Code Generation" -> "Runtime Library" setting (which you have set to "Multi-Threaded Debug DLL") controls what version of the C and C++ runtime you compile and link against, and has nothing to do with 3rd party libraries (such as "MyGUIEngine").

To change the version of "MyGUIEngine" you link to, change the value in "Linker" -> "Input" -> "Additional Dependancies" to "MyGUIEngine_d.lib" for the Debug configuration, and "MyGUIEngine.lib" for the Release configuration.

Comment: Yes, the strange thing is that MyGUIEngine.lib is not set as additional dependency, neither in release nor in debug. But that helped me finding the problem, there was in pragma in code: #pragma comment(lib,"MyGUIEngine.lib")

Comment: Yep, that'll do it.  That #pragma is the equivalent of setting the library as an additional dependency, just a different way to go about it.  You could do something like "#ifdef _DEBUG #pragma comment(lib, "MyGUIEngine_d.lib") #else #pragma comment(lib, "MyGUIEngine.lib") #endif if you want to stick with that approach.  (sorry about the formatting, can't type code in comments)

Comment: Thx, I'll do the #ifdef _Debug conditional. Actually I dont think its a good way to bind libraries within code via #pragma comment(lib, <somelib>) - you dont see it when looking in project properties and you have to search for it within the code.

Comment: I 100% agree, and I honestly have never used the #pragma method myself, nor would I ever if given the choice.